# Error al generar Condicional en PHP

Tags: php, condiciones

Tengo 2 select box en un formulario y cada uno solo contiene 2 opciones "Si" y "No"
Necesito formar una estructura condicional para mostrar una página DISTINTA en cada OPCIÓN al enviar por metodo post con el botón, pero no logro conseguirlo. Por favor ayúdenme.

El algoritmo es el sig.

- Tenemos un formulario con 2 selectbox con dos opciones cada uno. si/no y también:
- 4 páginas: pag1.php, pag2.php, pag3.php, pag4.php
- Si selectbox1 es SI y selectbox2 es SI = redirecciona -> pag1.php
- Si selectbox1 es SI y selectbox2 es NO = redirecciona -> pag2.php
- Si selectbox1 es NO y selectbox2 es NO = redirecciona -> pag3.php
- Si selectbox1 es SI y selectbox2 es NO = redirecciona -> pag4.php

Dejo solo el código php:

```
 <?php
if($_POST['si1'] == 1 ){
header("cuestionario4-50.php");
}
elseif($_POST['no0'] == 1 ){
header("pag1.php");
}
elseif($_POST['si11'] == 1 ){
header("pag2.php");
}
elseif($_POST['no00'] == 1 ){
header("pag3.php");
}
else {
header("pag4.php");
} 
?>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que llevas al momento y las dudas que tienes

Comment: Todo esta descrito en la pregunta, lo unico que no agregue fue el código HTML pero es solamente 2 combobox dentro de un form y un botón para envíar lo seleccionado. Este código HTML lo tengo en el mismo php.

Comment: <form action="MismaPagina.php">
    <select>
    <label>PREGUNTA 1</label>
 <option id="si1" name="si1" value="1">SI</option>
    <option id="no0" name="no0" value="1">NO</option>
 </select>
    <label>PREGUNTA 2</label>
 <option id="si11" name="si11" value="1">SI</option>
    <option id="no00" name="no00" value="1">NO</option>
 </select>
    <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
    </form>

Comment: si dame unos minutos esroy redactando una respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asignamos los valores recibidos de los `selectbox` a variables para manejarlos de un modo mas ordenado así:

```
//seleccion1/seleccion2 es un nombre de ejemplo del atributo name en el HTML
$selectBox1 = $_POST["seleccion1"]; 
$selectBox2 = $_POST["seleccion2"];
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior construimos un condicional que verifique su valor del siguiente modo:

```
if (selectBox1 == "si"  && selectBox2 == "si") {
    header('Location: pagina1.php');
}
elseif (selectBox1 == "si"  && selectBox2 == "no") {
    header('Location: pagina2.php');
}
elseif (selectBox1 == "no"  && selectBox2 == "no"){
    header('Location: pagina3.php');
}
elseif (selectBox1 == "si"  && selectBox2 == "no"){
    header('Location: pagina4.php');
}
else {
        header('Location: paginaDedault.php');
}
```

**Aclaraciones**

- Comparamos el valor de los `selectbox` asignados a variables con el símbolo de `==`
- De acuerdo con las indicaciones que estableces, debemos por cada condición, validar que se cumplan 2 estados por lo tanto hacemos uso del operador lógico `AND` representado por `&&`
- Dentro del método `header` hacemos uso de `Location` para que si las 2 estados en alguna de las condiciones se cumple, entonces redirija al usuario a la página apropiada
- Dentro del `else` indicamos solamente sin ninguna comprobación que redirija al usuario a una página por defecto en caso de que todas las condiciones que preceden **no** se cumplan

Comment: dentro del elseif se añaden los selectBox1 y selectBox cómo variables antes declaradas?

Comment: Así es @SuriGang'sHallen dentro de los `elseif` se pasan ambas variables evaluando si las 2 cumplen las condiciones indicadas por el uso del operador `AND`

Comment: Si es cuestión de agregar como dice Aprendiz el operador AND, en este caso &&

Comment: Estoy muy agradecido por tomarte tu tiempo amigo @Aprendiz ,funcionó gracias a ti¡